# Distributing a number into a list using avg of given number and comparing avg with each element of list

Tags: python, list, distribution

I have a number, for example `400` that I want to distribute in this list `[7, 50, 81, 109, 110, 95, 95, 75, 25]`, if the average of the given number (400/9~44.4) is greater than a given element in the list I just take the element, so the first step in the result list would look like this:

`[7, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 25]`

Then I recalculate the new average subtracting the values I have already taken ((400-7-25)/7~52.57) and I repeat this operation, maintaining the previous values I have already obtained, giving:

`[7, 50, None, None, None, None, None, None, 25]`

This process continues until the average obtained in each step is greater than a given (and not already distributed) item in the list, so now the avg is (400-7-25-50)/6=53, and the condition is no longer met, so the number i have to put is just this average, obtaining the result:

`[7, 50, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 25]`

For now I have this piece of code, that represents the first iteration:

```
original_number = 400
number_newavg = original_number
list_to_distribute = [7, 50, 81, 109, 110, 95, 95, 75, 25]
items_remaining = len(list_to distribute)
result_list = [None] * items_remaining
average = number_newavg/items_remaining

for i in range(len(list_to_distribute)):
   if average > list_to_distribute[i]:
      result_list[i] = list_to_distribute[i]
      number_newavg = number_newavg - result_list[i]
      items_remaining -= 1
      if items_remaining != 0:
         average = number_newavg/items_remaining

[7, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 25]
```

Is there any way to do this operation in a more elegant way (maybe using a while loop), to not need various for loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `while` approach.  I used a comparison between floats as breaking condition and could not be optimal. An alternative is to count the amount of `None` in the lists, hence the comparison is performed between integers.

```
number = 400
reference_list = [7, 50, 81, 109, 110, 95, 95, 75, 25]

N = len(reference_list)
avg = number / N

# initialize final list
result = [None] * N

# initial step
while True:
    # update    
    for i, v in enumerate(reference_list):
        if v < avg:
            result[i] = v

    # temporary list for compuatation only
    res = list(filter(None, result))
    n = len(res)
    avg_new = (number - sum(res)) / (N - n)

    # breaking condition
    if avg == avg_new: # comparison between floats!
        break

    # update average
    avg = avg_new

# replace possible None's with average
for i, v in enumerate(result):
    if v is None:
        result[i] = int(avg)

# display final list
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a recursive approach:

```
def spread(N,A):
    avg    = N/len(A)
    redo,B = zip(*[(i,a) for i,a in enumerate(A) if a > avg])
    if len(redo)==len(A):
        return [int(avg)]*len(A)
    for i,n in zip(redo,spread(N+sum(B)-sum(A),list(B))):
        A[i] = n
    return A
```

output:

```
A = [7, 50, 81, 109, 110, 95, 95, 75, 25]

R = spread(400,A)

print(R)
[7, 50, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 25]
```